# How to set image alt text to be fontawsome in asp.net?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, html, font-awesome

I am developing a website using ASP.Net. In the navbar, I put the profile photo of the current logged-in user.
In case the user doesn't have a profile photo, I want to show an alt text.
can I use fontawsome in the alt text?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot next an html tag within another for instance

```
<img alt="<i class="fas fa"
```

Im sure you can see the problem right away

You may however be able to use an HTML Entity
http://dnozay.github.io/cheatsheet/2014/09/23/fontawesome.html

Hopefully this helps

Comment: I tried this, but it didn't work:  <img src="wrong/path" alt="&#xf041;">

Comment: Only other option you have is nest the image in a wrapper div, and dynamically using javascript to trigger a js function with a response . Write output and use the js function set the innerhtml of the div with set id to be that of a fontawesome character if the src property of a var image = new Image() does not have a width or height when the src is set